# std::ofstream repeats and looses written data for no reason

Tags: c++, file, ofstream

I've just witnessed an insanely bizzare behaviour of the `std::ofstream::write` method. I am writing my own handling of Windows' BMP file format which includes saving a bitmap to a file - that's as an introduction. Here is a subroutine responsible for writing the header of the bitmap file, given reference to `std::ofstream` object.

```
void
BitmapFileManager::FileHeader::save(std::ofstream& fout) const
{
    word        w;  
    dword       dw; 
    char const* cw  = reinterpret_cast<char*>(w );
    char const* cdw = reinterpret_cast<char*>(dw);
    uint const  sw  = sizeof(w );
    uint const  sdw = sizeof(dw);

    fout.write(&sig1, sizeof(sig1));
    fout.write(&sig2, sizeof(sig2));
    dw = toLittleEndian(size);         fout.write(cdw, sdw);
    w  = toLittleEndian(reserved1);    fout.write(cw , sw );
    w  = toLittleEndian(reserved2);    fout.write(cw , sw );
    dw = toLittleEndian(pixelsOffset); fout.write(cdw, sdw);
}
```

The only thing to mark here is that `sig1` and `sig2` are both of type `char`, `sizeof(word) = 2` and `sizeof(dword) = 4`. This code should result in twice writing a byte to a file, then a four byte chunk, two two byte chunks and finally a four byte chunk.

Take look at the hex dump of the result (there are also some things that follow, but ignore them):

```
00000000  42 4d 42 4d 00 00 00 05  00 05 42 4d 00 00 28 00  |BMBM......BM..(.|
```

`sig1` and `sig2` are printed twice, with a proper value which actually is `B` and `M`, at the beginning and for some strange reason also at 11th and 12th byte. I don't recognize other values among this line. But look what happens if I add a debug byte between every `write`:

```
void
BitmapFileManager::FileHeader::save(std::ofstream& fout) const
{
    word        w;  
    dword       dw; 
    char const* cw  = reinterpret_cast<char*>(w );
    char const* cdw = reinterpret_cast<char*>(dw);
    uint const  sw  = sizeof(w );
    uint const  sdw = sizeof(dw);

    char nil = '*';
    fout.write(&sig1, sizeof(sig1));
    fout.write(&nil, sizeof(nil));
    fout.write(&sig2, sizeof(sig2));
    fout.write(&nil, sizeof(nil));
    dw = toLittleEndian(size);         fout.write(cdw, sdw);
    fout.write(&nil, sizeof(nil));
    w  = toLittleEndian(reserved1);    fout.write(cw , sw );
    fout.write(&nil, sizeof(nil));
    w  = toLittleEndian(reserved2);    fout.write(cw , sw );
    fout.write(&nil, sizeof(nil));
    dw = toLittleEndian(pixelsOffset); fout.write(cdw, sdw);
    fout.write(&nil, sizeof(nil));
}
```

Hex dump becomes

```
00000000  42 2a 4d 2a 6c 3b 78 a0  2a 00 05 2a 00 05 2a 6c  |B*M*l;x?*..*..*l|
00000010  3b 78 a0 2a 28 00 00 00  28 00 00 00 28 00 00 00  |;x?*(...(...(...|
```

It seems like it's perfectly alright. There are no duplicates, and the `*` divides the string into sequence of `1-1-4-2-2-4` bytes as it should. Could someone help me find the reason of this? Is it a bug at compilation? I use `gcc version 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5490)` on Mac OS X Leopard with -O2 but other levels didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a minimal standalone test-case?  (see http://sscce.org)

Comment: Surely you meant to write `char const* cw = reinterpret_cast<char>(&w)` (note the `&` operator at the end) instead of `...(w)`, and likewise for `cdw`/`dw`?  I'm surprised that runs without crashing.

Comment: I surely did. Now it works flawlessly. The behaviour is still strange though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam Rosenfield nailed it.  You were taking the contents of a w (a word) and treating it as a pointer... and then all hell broke loose.  Same thing for dw.

Random garbage after that...